# Angular animation: :leave ( * => void) not working as :enter (void => * ) is working

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am new to angular animation. I have a concern as why **:enter** is working absolutely fine. But **:leave** isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
    animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      transition('void => *', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate(4000)]),
      transition('* => void', [animate(4000, style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
  ]
```

I want to animate as **div** element leaves the DOM.

Stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leave-animation-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the animation is linked *inside* an `*ngIf` and not at the same level:

```html
<!-- container with ngIf --> 
<div *ngIf="show">
  <!-- element being animated -->
  <div @fade class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap">
    <!-- other content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

What is happening is that when `ngIf` switches from false to true, your animated elements get rendered and the animation triggers.

When `ngIf` switches from true to false, there is no animation on the div being destroyed, so Angular doesn't handle any, and destroys (removes from DOM) the element. Everything inside it is disposed immediately, so the animation doesn't trigger (or triggers in the heaven of removed DOM elements, where no one can see it, but I'm digressing).

To solve your problem, just put the `@fade` on the same element with the `*ngIf`.

Comment: Thank you @A. Chiesa for explaining this solution in detail & now it is working like a charm.. ~ Cheers... I want to ask you one more thing that in the current situation can I get the same result with `setTimeout()` triggered before living the DOM ???

Comment: I suppose, "yes", kinda. You really cannot use :leave, with the ngIf on another element. This because ngIf is going to destroy itself immediately. With a setTimeout you could just delay the abrupt removal you where seeing. But, you could in principle use an animation with state `@fade="fadeState"` (and set a value of "removing" or whatever suits your use case), and trigger the ngIf removal with a setTimeout.

Comment: Once again Thank you @A. Chiesa for the suggestion. I am looking forward to it.

Comment: If you want to coordinate multiple animations, I would suggest reading the (not really easy, but ultra dense) Angular Docs page regarding complex animations: https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences. In this scenario, you would animate the single elements using `query` and still put the `@fade` on the topmost div container. The idea is you set a state on the global container, and each state transition animates sub elements differently, in parallel or in sequence.

Comment: Just pay attention in animating "non animatable" properties, like `display`. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Sure... looking forward with your suggestions.

Comment: As @A. Chiesa's suggested solution [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-enter-leave-dom-solution) is the stackblitz link of working solution to this question